# Deploying .net core app to docker gives "Microsoft.DotNet.Props" not found error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, .net-core, dockerfile

I am having Windows 10 Home operating system.
I have installed Docker toolbox.
I want to deploy my .net core application to Docker.
I created my Docker file by referring to following helpful article:
https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-deploy-asp-net-core-on-linux-with-docker

My docker file is as follows:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

But when I run, docker command for creating image, it gives me error.

```
user@machine_name MINGW64 path to solution
$  docker build -t helloWorld:core .
```

Error:

```
/app/Web.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.0-rc4-004771/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/DotNet/Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
The command 'dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can someone please guide, what is going wrong over here, as I am completely new to Docker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see `Web.xproj` in your error, look like you have the same problem as described in [this github issue](https://github.com/Kwoth/NadekoBot/issues/1047). The root of such problem is that Microsoft updated their docker to the newest SDK which moves back to `.csproj` from `project.json`. The solution is to use another, `1.1-sdk-projectjson` tag:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-projectjson
```

Note on [microsoft/dotnet/](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) docker page:

> The `latest` tag no longer uses the project.json project format, but has now been updated to be csproj/MSBuild-based. If you do not wish to migrate your existing projects to MSBuild simply change your Dockerfile to use the `1.1.0-sdk-projectjson` or `1.1.0-sdk-projectjson-nanoserver` tag. Going forward, new .NET Core sdk images will be MSBuild-based.

Comment: I changed image name from "microsoft/dotnet:latest" to "microsoft/1.1-sdk-projectjson" in docker file. But it gives me following error "repository microsoft/1.1-sdk-projectjson not found: does not exist or no pull access".

Comment: @PurnimaNaik sorry, `1.1.0-sdk-projectjson` is a tag, not image. I have edited answer. You need to use `microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-projectjson`

Comment: Now restore works partially. It is not able to  resolve my .net core libraries. It gives me error "Unable to resolve 'Logging.Interfaces (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'". Can you please tell me why I am getting this? I am getting this error for all my libraries.

Comment: @PurnimaNaik it is difficult to say exactly without your project.json file. Recheck that you use correct package versions  for  1.1 sdk version. Like `"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",`, not `"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",`

Comment: But I am getting this error for the project libraries created by me, and not for Microsoft dll. Microsoft libraries restore is working fine. Should i share my project.json file?

Comment: @PurnimaNaik as after solving problem `X` you have faced with another problem `Y`, I suggest creating a new SO question where, yes, you will need to add your `project.json(s)` and other related information about your project.

Comment: I have posted new question, will you please have a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198968/docker-unable-to-resolve-net-standard-class-libraries-on-deploying-net-core-a

Comment: Does anyone know if this project.json container will be maintained or are we forced back to the prehistoric csproj file? (Myself and everyone I know has not installed Visual Studio 17 for a reason!)

Comment: Thanks a lot:) my project does not have a projection file. So, I used the following FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk to get me sorted.