# Docker unable to resolve .net standard class libraries, on deploying .net core app to Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am deploying .net core app to Docker.

My docker file is as follows, which is added in my .net core application:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-projectjson

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Its not able to resolve .net standard class libraries, which are added to my .net core application.

My project structure is as follows:

```
Core folder

   -Logging.Interfaces .net std project

   -Logging.Entities .net std project

Infrastructure folder

   -Infrastructure.Logging .net std project

Services folder

   -Services .net std project

Web folder

   -Web .net core application
```

Dependencies section of project.json of Web application is as follows:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "DomainInterfaces": "1.0.0-*",
    "Core.Logging.Interfaces": "1.0.0-*",
    "Core.Logging.Entities": "1.0.0-*",
    "Infrastructure.Logging": "1.0.0-*"
  },
```

When I run following command, for creating image, it gives me error:

```
user@machine_name MINGW64 path to solution
$  docker build -t helloWorld:core .

Unable to resolve 'Core.Logging.Interfaces (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
    Unable to resolve 'Core.Logging.Entities (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
    Unable to resolve 'Services (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
    Unable to resolve 'Infrastructure.Logging (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
    Unable to resolve 'DomainInterfaces (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.
```

Can someone please guide, what is going wrong over here, as I am completely new to Docker.

Comment: where do you save dockerfile?

Comment: My docker file is in web project, which is .net core application. And all other projects are added as reference in my web application.

Comment: You should be tried to place dockerfile in solution as /src folder.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be tried to create a Dockerfile on solution level as following structure:

/YourProject

- src

  - Core
  - Infrastructure
  - Services
  - WebApp
- Dockerfile

And changes content of Dockerfile to:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-projectjson

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/src/WebApp

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Hope this help!

Comment: When I change Dockerfile, and run docker build command, I get "Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directory" error.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the answer and check the structure again?

Answer (score 0):

My dot net core application does not have a project.json file either. I fixed my problem with the follow: `FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk` instead of `FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-projectjson`